# Triggering a shell script from MySQL without any 3rd party libraries

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

Is it possible to call a bash script file in linux using a trigger in MySQL?
I've been searching for the answer online and I ran into this articles:

http://patternbuffer.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/triggering-shell-script-from-mysql/

http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html?showComment=1416010000049#c2028082587789719436

But I was wondering if it's possible to do it without any 3rd party libraries like UDF for example. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You think the web pages are wrong when they say it's not possible?

Comment: UDF isn't third party, you can write it yourself.

Comment: well, there's lot of wrong information on the internet. and By 3rd party I mean that I can use just the installation of mysql to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible for a standard MySQL instance to invoke an external process without using a UDF or a plugin.

Most sites write some kind of polling application to check for presence of data that needs to be processed, and then invoke the shell script from that application.

Another solution would be to process the binary log, looking for bin log events that indicate data appeared that needs to be processed by the shell script. Processing the bin log in this way is called *change data capture*. There are a couple of tools to do this, see my answer to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63681/does-mysql-have-a-version-of-change-data-capture